# ConTeXt: Text wrapping around images with complex outline

Tags: graphics, context, wrap

I'm a very beginner on ConTeXt, coming from Scribus and InDesign. I would like to know if is it possible to get a text flowing around an image with complex/winding border on ConTeXt as in the images belows?

It can be either a custom/manually drew outline or the text advancing over the transparent part of a PNG image.

[image: Example: Text flowing around winding borders]

[image: Example: Text flowing around winding borders]

I've just found nothing on the documentation and web but text surrounding square border of images.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a complex issue, and you will need a lot of manual tweaking (maybe Scribus and InDesign are better tools if you need to do this a lot). You should read about `parshape` for TeX. With ConTeXt you cannot do much more, but you can get some help by using MetaFun to make the shape for you (so that you do not have to enter numbers yourself). In the [MetaFun](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf), Section 10.6 on libraries, you will find the `txt` library, with examples.

I started with one example for you. It is by no means complete, and there are, as you will see if you play with it, some limititations. I could for example not put a section headings inside it without breaking it. Also a displayed formula inside messed it up.

See the mentioned section in the MetaFun manual for explanation of the different parameters.

```
% Just some setups
\definepapersize[square][width=5in,height=5in]
\setuppapersize[square]

\setupbodyfont[libertinus,10pt]

\setuplayout[
    margin=0pt,
    backspace=0.75in,
    topspace=0.75in,
    width=3.5in,
    height=3.75in,
    footer=0in,
    header=0in,
    location=middle,
]

% Here the important things start
\useMPlibrary[txt]

\startuseMPgraphic{nododo1}
path p ;
numeric w, h ;
w := 3.5in ;
h := 3.75in ;
p := (0, h) -- (0, 0.5*h) -- (0.35*w, 0.5*h) -- (0.5*w, 0.25*h) -- (0.5*w, 0) -- (w, 0) -- (w, h) -- cycle ;
build_parshape(p, 0pt, 0, 0, \baselinedistance, \strutheight, \strutdepth, \strutheight) ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{nododo2}
path p ;
numeric w, h ;
w := 3.5in ;
h := 0.8*3.5in ;
p := unitsquare xyscaled(w,h) ;
build_parshape(p, 0pt, 0, 0, \baselinedistance, \strutheight, \strutdepth, \strutheight) ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[nododo1][\useMPgraphic{nododo1}]
\defineoverlay[nododo2][\useMPgraphic{nododo2}]

\startshapetext[nododo1, nododo2]
\forgetall
\setupalign[verytolerant,stretch,normal]
\samplefile{knuth}\par
\samplefile{douglas}
\stopshapetext

\starttext
% This just place the figure
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=pagegraphics]
\definelayer[pagegraphics][
    width=\paperwidth,
    height=\paperheight,
    ]
\setlayer[pagegraphics][corner={left,bottom},location={right,top}]{\externalfigure[proofs][height=0.5\paperheight]}

% This is for the shaped paragraphs
\getshapetext
\getshapetext

This is some text after the whole thing. Back to normal. Not much to see.

\stoptext
```

Note here that we use two MetaFun pictures, and that the content is continuing from the first one to the second.

[image: A picture with a parshape]

The nice picture is drawn by my friend Sofia.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to create an SVG outline of the image and convert that to MetaFun instructions without having to tweak various numbers by hand. If you have the original image, then you can skip many steps that follow because presumably you can get the original image without the background. Otherwise, using the [GIMP](https://gimp.org/) and [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), create an outline as follows:

1. Open the image.
2. Remove the text.
3. Click the magic wand icon (fuzzy select tool).
4. Set **Threshold** and **Radius** to something like 5 and 5.
5. Use the tool to roughly select the background (e.g., hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the background portions):
   [image: Selection]
6. Use the rectangle or ellipse select tool along with <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> clicks to edit the selection (not terribly important, we'll fix any issues momentarily).
7. Press <kbd>Del</kbd> to delete the selection to see the result.
   [image: Outline]
8. Click **Select >> Invert**.
9. Optionally, click **Select >> Grow** and set the value to 2.
10. Click **Windows >> Dockable Dialogs >> Paths** to open the Path dialog.
11. Click **Select >> To Path** to copy the path.
12. Right-click on the **Selection** outline in the Path dialog.
13. Click **Export Path**.
14. Set a file name (e.g., `outline.svg`).
15. Click **Save**.
16. Close GIMP.
17. Open Inkscape.
18. Open the SVG file (e.g., `outline.svg`).
    [image: Inkscape outline]
19. Fix anomalies:

    1. Click to select the outline.
    2. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit the nodes.
    3. Click and drag the mouse over the unwanted nodes.
    4. Press <kbd>Del</kbd> to delete nodes.
20. Click **File >> Save As**.
21. Select **Plain SVG**.
22. Confirm replacing.

At this point you'll have an SVG file of the outline, but it won't convert to MetaPost cleanly. To resolve this, use a tool such as [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) to minify and normalize the path coordinates. You'll get something like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 316 441"><path fill="none" stroke="#000" d="M125 119c-2.87 10.67-8.65 3.55-10.39-3-2.65-9.98 1.32-10.67 4.98-17.04L128.43 80c1.65-3.76 3.45-10.98 7.62-12.36 4.65-1.54 8.56 3.55 11.67 4.69H158c13.93.23 9.4-1.38 14.96-1.85H187c4.92-.74 6.72-4.21 10 1.52 3.69-1.53 7.93-5 11.95-2.96 4.39 2.22 4.56 6.81 5.55 10.96l2.6 9 2.1 11c.3 2.61 1.44 8.27 0 10.67-1.4 3.09-4.37.58-6.2-.67-1.6 4.17-3.15 9.17-3.91 13.58l-.7 5.43c-.56 1.75-1.72 3.47-2.74 4.99-3.86 5.78-5.73 7.59-12.65 6-.32 7.41 4.49 10.68 11 12.9 10.37 3.53 22.04 3.04 28.35 14.14l3.62 8.96c1.83 3.46 3.97 4.66 5.61 9l3.58 12c2.17 4.09 5.7 5.61 7.1 9.09 1.27 3.15-.12 5.61 1.47 10.91 1.73 5.75 9.96 22.75 14.17 26.54 1.91 1.72 3.5 1.61 4.54 2.52 2.77 2.42.46 10.03 4.32 11.39 2.58.91 5-4.05 8.2-5.28 2.44-.94 3.61.51 3.26 2.89-.47 3.2-4.32 7.98-5 10.51-1.78 6.71 5.65 11.73 9.37 15.8 2.57 2.82 4.23 8.91 5.77 12.63l3.78 8c1.98 5.36 4.76 20.16 4.86 26 .08 4.95 2.25 11.73-2.23 15.14-3.3 2.26-7.29 2.12-10.73 0-1.52-.72-3.36-2.72-5.24-2.4-2.15.38-3.91 3.83-6.84 4.44-2.72.57-4.91-1.55-7.96-1.7-2.65-.13-4.58 1.29-8 1.12l-21-5.06c-7.55-2.58-11.59-8.37-20-9.54l2.08 26 2.58 30-.58 7 .58 7-1.62 14 .69 8-1.69 10-1.78 8.01-7.26.99H109c-3.23-5.91-6.49-4.09-9.55-10.02-2.93-5.68-1.29-17.26 1.18-22.98 1.96-4.55 2.81-3.85 5.37-11-4.19 1.02-5.71 1.14-10 .58-4.66-.61-10.22.17-13.45-3.73-4.13-4.66-1.08-14.16 0-19.85 1.88-8.43 8.72-31.92 7.89-39-.26-2.23-1.56-4.9-2.44-7-2.48.75-4.79 1.3-7 2.72-10.25 6.63-16.25 21.51-16.91 33.28-.25 4.49.38 7.29 3.02 10.99 3.24 4.54 8.78 8.42 7.49 14.91-.77 3.83-5.2 5.27-8.6 4.17-4.6-1.49-9.78-7.83-11.86-12.07l-3.86-8.95c-1.85-2.65-6.55-5.67-9.28-8.05l-.55 11 3.43 16.71L41 395c1.76 3.37 3.17 6.94 5.53 9.96 2.29 2.95 4.7 4.17 5.32 8.08.41 2.51.37 9.56-1.02 11.55-2.56 3.93-10.35 2.5-13.32 0L21.04 401l-4.12-8.83C13.82 387.35 5.39 381.06 0 379V163c.01-5.57 1.87-14.35 9.02-14.75 4.1-.23 6.62 2.58 9.26 3.84L37 159c2.34-6.65 9.1-2.14 13.24-9.18 1.5-2.6.17-5.07 0-7.82-.35-4.85 1.88-7.1 0-11-1.22-2.64-4.29-4.99-4.95-9-.37-2.28.76-7.64 4.17-5.83 1.69.89 2.2 4.19 4.76 6.6 2.94 2.75 12.34 2.45 15.56.93 7.18-3.4-.38-9.59-1.33-13.7-.78-3.33.77-6.03 3.22-4.83 1.48.72 2.85 3.32 3.96 4.63 1.47 1.74 3.98 3.4 4.76 5.41 1.58 4.08-2.18 8.33-2.3 12.79-.09 3.11 1.8 6.61 2.44 10l.61 9.32c.76 2.34 13.46 11.92 15.86 12.54 2.58.66 4.67-1.18 7-1.98 2.97-1.02 5.91-.87 9-.88 1.65-4.66 3.56-3.53 8-3 .88-4.61 1.33-6.47 6-8-1.53-1.65-5.41-4.87-5.38-7.11.06-4 5.41-5.17 8.07-8.11 2.19-2.43 2.53-5.73 3.31-8.78l-8-3zm-71.74-15.83c4.69-.55 3.29 3.71 1.48 4.66-1.91 1.01-5.02-.93-1.48-4.66zM45 343h-2c-.84 5.99-3.34 12.1-1 18 4.72-10.29 3.48-7.42 3-18zm-18 98c1.23-6.97 5.45-4.96 8 0h-8z"/></svg>
```

From there:

1. Run `rsvg-convert` to convert SVG to PDF

   ```
   rsvg-convert -f pdf -o outline.pdf outline.svg
   ```
2. Run `pdftops` to convert PDF to PS

   ```
   pdftops outline.pdf outline.ps
   ```
3. Run `pstoedit` to convert PostScript to MetaPost

   ```
   pstoedit outline.ps outline.mp
   ```

Now you can follow [mickep's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646444/2148) without having to tweak numbers by hand. That is, take the output from `outline.mp` and assign the `draw` command to the `path p` variable. Such as:

```
draw (93.750000,241.500000)..controls (91.597702,233.496002) and (87.261703,238.835999)..(85.957001,243.750000)
..controls (83.968803,251.233994) and (86.949203,251.753998)..(89.691399,256.531006)
```

Becomes:

```
path p;
p := (93.750000,241.500000)..controls (91.597702,233.496002) and (87.261703,238.835999)..(85.957001,243.750000)
..controls (83.968803,251.233994) and (86.949203,251.753998)..(89.691399,256.531006)
```